# Inferencing based on property relation with an instance

Tags: ontology, protege

It is possible to inference let's say a `Wine` based on a property relation with a certain instance. This instance is a member of the class `Region` but does not get classified further by the ontology. So from the ontology we know it's a `Region`.

It it possible for me to make a new inferencing class called `Australian Wines`? An instance belongs to this class when it's a `Wine` and it has a property relation with the instance `SydneyEastRegion`. I can't get this to work because I can only make inferences based on relations where the instance is getting defined by the class it belongs too. So when the instance 'sydney region' is a member of class 'Sydney Region' it does work. Curious to know if this is possible. Cheers.

[example ontology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjcte.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the situation correctly, you wish to say:

An Australian Wine is a wine whose hasRegion property is an Australian region (where Australian region is an instance, not a class of regions).

This should be something like

`AustralianWine subClassOf Wine and hasProperty value {AustralianRegion}`

This is a HasValue restriction, which provides an explicit set of individuals rather than a class range for `hasProperty`.